# Center tab bar icons Vertically - React Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios, react-native-navigation

Im just having an issues with creating a custom navigation tab bar and centering the icons vertically. It looks like it been pushed up a bit as per below screenshot:

[image]

This is the style i have for the tab navigation:

```
tabBarOptions: {
    activeTintColor: '#e91e63',
    labelStyle: {
        fontSize: 12,
    },
    style: {
        position: 'absolute',
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        width: DEVICE_WIDTH * 0.94,
        borderBottomLeftRadius: 33,
        borderBottomRightRadius: 33,
        borderTopLeftRadius: 10,
        borderTopRightRadius: 10,
        bottom: 12,
        marginLeft: '2.8%',
        shadowColor: '#000000',
        shadowOffset: {
          width: 0,
          height: 0.3
        },
        shadowRadius: 5,
        shadowOpacity: 0.1
    }
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to fix this by specifying a style for the icon:

```
<Icon
    name="user"
    color={tintColor}
    size={28}
    style={{ textAlignVertical: 'center' }}
/>
```